# Allow all actions for authentication in integration test cakephp

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, integration-testing, cakephp-3.0

I'm currently trying to write an integration test for some controller whereby it is necessary to send an authentication header. In my controller I have some actions made public accessible through the following code:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException;
use Cake\Utility\Security;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
   public function initialize()
   {
       parent::initialize();
       $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'token']); // public methods
   }
  .....
}
```

Now I have an integration test case in which I want to allow that all actions are possible to access without authentication. Is there any simple way to make this possible?

Integration case code:

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use App\Controller\Api\UsersController;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;

class ApiPicturesControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase{
   public $fixtures = [
      'app.albums',
      'app.pictures',
      'app.users',
      'app.comments',
      'app.users_albums'
   ];
   public function setUp(){
       parent::setUp();
       // Allow all actions
       // $this->Auth->allow();
   }
   public function testViewShouldPass(){
        $this->configRequest([
           'headers' => [
               'Accept' => 'application/json'
           ]
        ]);
        $data = $this->get('/api/pictures/1.json');
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would kinda defeat the purpose of integration testing, wouldn't it? Maybe what you're actually looking for, is accessing the action in an authenticated state?

Comment: Yes true, since I'm new to integration testing I'm not really sure how to mock the authentication for stateless authentication. Since I'm already stuck for a day trying to get this working, I now just want to bypass the authentication process and fix this later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it's possible to manipulate the controller in an overriden `\Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase::controllerSpy()` method, like

```
public function controllerSpy($event)
{
    parent::controllerSpy($event);

    if (isset($this->_controller)) {
        $this->_controller->Auth->allow();
    }
}
```

but as already mentioned in the comments, it would be better to properly authenticate your requests instead!

While integration tests do not necessarily have to be black-box tests, peering into the internals of the test subject isn't an overly good idea. Mocking certain parts in an integration test might be reasonable when you are looking for something in between "test everything" and "test units", ie larger groups of modules, but that should mostly only be necessary when heavy complexity is involved in a request.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase::controllerSpy()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.TestSuite.IntegrationTestCase.html#_controllerSpy)**
- **[API > \Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase::$_controller](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.TestSuite.IntegrationTestCase.html#$_controller)**

Comment: Thanks, this worked :). I know this isn't the way to eventually let the integration test case pass and therefore I will try to make the authentication part work.