# Mock auth cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, integration-testing, cakephp-3.0

Currently I'm trying to test a controller which uses the authentication component to retrieve the user id. Since I'm fairly new to unit/integration testing, I have no idea how to make this working. Moreover, all the content that I could find for this particular problem is written for Cakephp version 2.

Controller function:

```
 public function favorite(){
    // Particular line where the problem is occurring:
    $userId = $this->Auth->User()['id'];
    // Get all favorite pictures of the user
    $query = $this->UsersPictures->getFavoritePictures($userId);

    $results = $query->all();
    // Replace the link in the result set by a presigned url of Amazon
    foreach($results as $result){
        $result->picture->link = $this->Aws->getTokenizedItem($result->picture->link);
    }
    $this->set([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => [
            'pictures' => $results
        ],
        '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
    ]);
}
```

Integration test:

```
public function testFavoriteShouldPass(){
    $this->configRequest([
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]
    ]);
    $this->get('api/pictures/favorite/1.json');

    $expected = [
        'success' => true,
        'data' => [
                [
                'user_id' => 1,
                'picture_id' => 1,
                'created' => '2016-04-03T20:35:40+0000',
                'modified' => '2016-04-03T20:35:40+0000',
                'picture' => [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'album_id' => 1,
                    'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                    'link' => 'test',
                    'favorite' => true,
                    'created' => null,
                    'modified' => null,
                    'cover_photo' => true
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $response);
}
```

My question is how can I insert a user with a default id of 1 for $this->Auth->User()['id']. I saw in other questions that I need to use something that looks like this:

```
   $this->_controller->Auth
        ->staticExpects($this->any())
        ->method('user')
        ->will($this->returnValue([
            'id' => 1,
            'username' => 'admin',
            'created' => '2013-05-08 00:00:00',
            'modified' => '2013-05-08 00:00:00',
            'email' => 'me@me.com',
        ]));
```

However, I read that staticExpects is deprecated from phpunit version 3.8 (I'm using 5.2). How should I mock this?

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. The problem is that I want to assign a fixed value to $this->Auth->User('id') during testing (for instance user_id always 1). In this way, I can test whether the controller actions work like they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to azahar :), this worked for me:

```
public function controllerSpy($event)
{
    parent::controllerSpy($event);

    if (isset($this->_controller)) {
        $this->_controller->Auth->setUser([
            'id' => 1,
            'username' => 'testtesttesttest',
            'email' => 'john@doe.com',
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'uuid' => 'wepoewoweo-ew-ewewpoeopw',
            'sign_in_count' => 1,
            'current_sign_in_ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'active' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the  session data in your integration tests using `$this->session()`, for example (taken from cakephp book):

```
// Set session data
$this->session([
    'Auth' => [
        'User' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'username' => 'testing',
            // other keys.
        ]
    ]
]);
```

You can actually find it in their docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#controller-integration-testing

You can find it in the section

> Testing Actions That Require Authentication

If you want to use the same session data on each test you can use the setUp method of your integration test class, like so:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    // Set session data
    $this->session([
    'Auth' => [
        'User' => [
              'id' => 1,
              'username' => 'testing',
              // other keys.
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I forget to tell that I use stateless authentication whereby there isn't used any session. In normal situations this would be the way to go but I couldn't find anything for this particular problem in the Cakephp docs.

Comment: Have you tried the controllerSpy function? Like this:
   `public function controllerSpy($event)
    {
        parent::controllerSpy($event);

        if (isset($this->_controller)) {
        $this->_controller->Auth->setUser(['username' =>    'admin','is_admin' => true]);}
}`

Comment: Nice! That actually did the job. I already bypassed it with global state variables but this is a much better solution.

Comment: Ok, found this around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958132/allow-all-actions-for-authentication-in-integration-test-cakephp if you want to read the whole thing.